Need help with the transfer function of a lead-lag filter

I keep getting $$\frac{\operatorname{V_2}(s)}{\operatorname{V_1}(s)}=- \frac{1}{R_1 C_2} \cdot \frac{\left(R_1C_1s+1\right)\cdot\left(R_2C_2s+1\right)}{s}$$
which is improper and wrong. Help is much appreciated, I just need to know what's wrong with my attempt at solving the problem, please reopen


Hello,
How can you tell it is wrong?

Well, mostly because I haven't dealt with improper transfer functions throughout the whole course. Searched around for similar cases but couldn't find any; found this response as well. This problem also asks me to perform partial fraction expansion on the resulting transfer function, which I can't if its like so

You are close......Can you show what you have done so far?

@Tyassin added to the OP

Sorry for the confusion, but it actually looks correct. So it should be in the standard form to also do a Bode plot, with a couple of zeroes and a single pole.
The partial fraction expansion is to long gone for me :-)
but check something like this out: https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/BackGround/PartialFraction/PartialFraction.html

I get the same answer as you so, please explain why you think the answer is incorrect.

@Tyassin thank you for confirming the anwser

@Andyaka Well I thought filters would always get you proper transfer functions (search around the web too and found nothing), and so did my teacher as well, cuz he asks for the partial fraction expansion but there's only 1 pole... I'm mostly surprised as this is the first time I encounter an improper TF - and my teacher said we wouldn't be dealing with those, so I'm definitely asking him about this

Using the standard inverting amplifier with infinite Aol formula and an ideal opamp:
Let's see if I remember ;)
$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=-\frac{\text{v}_\text{o}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=-\frac{\text{R}_1\text{||}\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}{\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}=-\frac{\text{R}_1\cdot\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}{\text{R}_1+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{R}_2+\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}}$$
$$=-\frac{\text{R}_1\text{C}_1\text{s}+1}{\text{R}_1}\cdot\frac{\text{R}_2\text{C}_2\text{s}+1}{\text{sC}_2}=-\frac{\left(1+\text{R}_2\text{C}_2\text{s}\right)\left(1+\text{R}_1\text{C}_1\text{s}\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{C}_2\text{s}}\tag?$$
